# Wicked PDF gem works locally but displays different font when deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I’m trying to generate PDFs in a Rails 4.2 app using the Wicked PDF gem and everything works fine locally. However, when deployed to other environments the PDF renders but most* of the text is displayed as what appears to be characters from “[Cursor Font](http://search.cpan.org/dist/X11-Protocol-Other/lib/X11/CursorFont.pm)” which I've never seen before but it appears to be something bundled with X11.

*I say "most" because some of the PDF text renders normally if enclosed in certain html tags. For example, if I change p-tags to h1 tags, normal font is displayed, but obviously I don't want the entire document to look like one big header.

- I checked the logs; no errors are being generated.
- I’ve tried various combinations of Wicked gem versions and wkhtmltopdf binaries. Currently using `gem 'wicked_pdf'`and `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'`.
- I’ve closely followed the Wicked PDF set-up documentation to include
  PDF mime type, a wicked_pdf.rb initializer file, precompiled
  assets, and absolute asset paths. Currently using (although have tried many variations) `stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("pdf.css.scss")` and `javascript_include_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("application")`

Any ideas/advice on why this is happening is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your test HTML identical in production as it is in development?  Are you getting any request errors in production for the widked_pdf css and javascript files?  (Check the console, and see https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#asset-pipeline-usage)

Comment: Yes, the HTML is the exact same in all environments. We've specified which assets to precompile and have even tried directly precompiling on the server (using `rake assets:precompile`) in order to confirm that the correct asset files are precompiling (they are). We are not getting any errors in the logs. Is there something we should try running from the console? Thanks.

Comment: I meant the browser console, to be clear.  It sounds like the CSS is not getting loaded.  No 404 errors in the browser console for "pdf.css-(SHA)"?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But no, no errors in the browser console either.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I just went in and manually changed the font color in the CSS on the server and it did pick up the change, but when I tried to do the same thing and specify a different font-family, it kept the cursor font. So looks like it's picking up the CSS, just still overriding it with weird cursor characters. :/

Comment: I think the issue is that your page is trying to get rendered on the server, and the server doesn't have the fonts you are using. Have you set @font-face in your styles? 
Also steps 5 and 6 of [this document](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/wiki/Configuring-wicked_pdf-for-Bootstrap) could be of some help.

Comment: Thank you! We had previously tried following the steps on that page for configuring Wicked PDF and Bootstrap to no avail as well as several attempts at setting @font-face and custom fonts, but your comment lead me to continue exploring and I found [this fix](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/334#issuecomment-390851319) for Wicked issue #334 which seems to be working when I tested it on a small part of our code. If I can get it fully working with our app, I'll post a final solution. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: `@import`, `@font-face` etc, can cause issues due to CORS since wicked_pdf pulls the html content to a tempfile file and renders from there. Inlining your imports and using `wicked_asset_base64` can go a long way. If you `bundle open wicked_pdf` and drop in a pry after content is rendered, but before the actual `wkhtmltopdf` command is executed, you can open the html tempfile it creates in your browser and see if there's a CORS issue.